# Windows 10: How to disable the “Publisher couldn’t be verified” message

Tags: windows-10

Win10 (home) ver 2004. The following doesn't work:

https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-the-publisher-couldnt-be-verified-message-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hold the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> button, then press <kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the Run dialog box.
2. Type `regedit`, then click “OK”.
3. Navigate to key "Policies" at path "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies"
4. Right click on Policies and create 2 keys "Associations" and "Attachments".
5. Right click on Associations and select "New" > "String Value".
6. Name the value as "ModRiskFileTypes" and add the extensions you want. For e.g. `*.exe;*.msi;`
   [image]
7. Right click on Attachments and select "New" > "DWORD Value".
8. Name the value as "SaveZoneInformation" and put 1 in "Value data" field as shown:
   [image]
9. Open Run dialog box and type `inetcpl.cpl` and click on “OK”.
10. Select Security tab and click on “Custom level...”.
11. Make changes in Security Settings as shown
    [image]
12. Click “OK” in “Internet Properties” and close the window.